# How to obtain Prost! enum from String

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, prost

The generated enum type looks like this, although I don't really have access to the src as it's generated by [Prost!](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost) during the build:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, PartialOrd, Ord, ::prost::Enumeration)]
#[repr(i32)]
pub enum Fruit {
    Unspecified = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Lemon = 3,
    ...
```

I can get a `&str` from an enum like this:

```rust
let apple = Fruit::Apple;
assert_eq!(apple.as_str_name(), "APPLE");
```

This method is provided by Prost!.

But I want to get **the enum from a string**.

The [strum](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/) crate offers a solution except I can't edit the source code file. Maybe there's a hack using `include!()` to attach a macro annotation during the build stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prost_build` can be configured to attach arbitrary attributes to the generated code via [`type_attribute`](https://docs.rs/prost-build/latest/prost_build/struct.Config.html#method.type_attribute) and [`field_attribute`](https://docs.rs/prost-build/latest/prost_build/struct.Config.html#method.field_attribute):

```rust
// build.rs

Config::new()
    .type_attribute("Fruit", "#[derive(EnumString)]")
    .compile_protos(["src/fruit.proto"], &["src"])
    .unwrap();
```